# Background fixed & cover - Internet explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, background-attachment

http://apolytos.com/new/img/test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    background:url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:top center;
    margin:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Internet Explorer 11 is NOT covering; view the link provided.  If I remove the :fixed, it covers as it's supposed to, however the bg scrolls with content on page which is not desired.  There appears to be a conflict with these 2 lines of code in IE.

Comment: Yo, you got a jsfiddle?

Comment: negative there ghostrider

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it should work well.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: background-size doesn't need prefixes

Comment: it does when you use outdated browser

Comment: you can check out this link [Perfect Full Page Background](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the background image as replace element, which means use as  tag

Comment: would you might giving an example?  I'm not completely following

Comment: try to put lyk <img src="image.png" alt="image" class="img"> and .img{  position:absolute; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;}